# Protocols with associated types in Swift 4.2

Tags: swift-protocols, swift4.2

I have a question about protocols with associated types, that occurred after updating to Xcode 10 and Swift 4.2.

Before I had a protocol:

```
protocol ViewModelBased: class {
    associatedtype ViewModel
    var viewModel: ViewModel { get set }
}
```

and a VC implementing it.

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, ViewModelBased {
    var viewModel: EntitiesViewModel!
}
```

After update to Xcode 10 I get and error saying MyViewController doesn't conform to the protocol and I have to declare the property as:

```
var viewModel: ViewModel! { get set }
```

Anyone has any idea why there is difference as I don't get it?

Comment: “I have to unwrap the property in the protocol” You’re not unwrapping anything. You’re declaring a type. An Optional type.

Comment: Probably pretty well covered by https://swift.org/blog/iuo/.

Comment: There is no unwrapping here! The exclamation mark used to unwrap a value is not the exclamation  mark used to declare a type.

Comment: @matt So the ! means that I implicitly declare a type that can be unwrapped or something else?

Comment: You do not implicitly do anything. You are declaring a type! The question is, what type? There used to be a type called ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional, but now there isn’t. Read the link I gave you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically your code was always dubious and now you’ve been caught:

```
protocol ViewModelBased: class {
    associatedtype ViewModel
    var viewModel: ViewModel { get set }
}
class MyViewController: UIViewController, ViewModelBased {
    var viewModel: EntitiesViewModel!
}
```

In the protocol adopter MyViewController, what type do you claim corresponds to ViewModel? It seems you think it should be EntitiesViewModel. And the compiler permitted this to slide, allowing the implicitly unwrapped Optional wrapping a type to be substituted for the type itself.

But now there is no implicitly unwrapped Optional type; the type `EntitiesViewModel!` is effectively the same as the type `EntitiesViewModel?`, an Optional wrapping EntitiesViewModel. So if you want EntitiesViewModel to be ViewModel, and if you want this property’s type to be an Optional wrapping EntitiesViewModel, the protocol must declare this property’s type as an Optional wrapping ViewModel.

Comment: I don't understand the downvoting of the question as is not so clear, at least for me, but whatever. Thanks for helping understand the difference.

Comment: I don’t understand it either, but downvotes are anonymous so there is no point discussing it. We cannot ask the downvoter for his reasoning.

Comment: Well you are right, but it means that my question is useless, although is a basic one to understand a fundamental concept, which maybe is not so clear for others too.